# Consolidate Click Functions

Tags: jquery, consolidation

How do I consolidate the following?

```
    var vid01 = $("#vid01");

    $("#img01").live('click', function() {
        $("#aaaLogo").fadeOut(100);
        $("#frame").fadeIn(100, function() {
            vid01.show(setVideo(0));
        });
    });

    $("#img02").live('click', function() {
        $("#aaaLogo").fadeOut(100);
        $("#frame").fadeIn(100, function() {
            vid01.show(setVideo(1));
        });
    });

    $("#img03").live('click', function() {
        $("#aaaLogo").fadeOut(100);
        $("#frame").fadeIn(100, function() {
            vid01.show(setVideo(2));
        });
    });

    $("#img04").live('click', function() {
        $("#aaaLogo").fadeOut(100);
        $("#frame").fadeIn(100, function() {
            vid01.show(setVideo(3));
        });
    });
```

I've been trying for a while but I can't figure it out. Here's one attempt:

```
var vid01 = $("#vid01");

        $("#img01, #img02, #img03, #img04").live('click', function() {
            $("#aaaLogo").fadeOut(100);
            $("#frame").fadeIn(100, function() {
                vid01.show(setVideo(0));
                vid01.show(setVideo(1));
                vid01.show(setVideo(2));
                vid01.show(setVideo(3));
            });
        });
```

The above attempt only shows the last video. I know why, just don't know how to map each `id` to each of those `functions`.

This isn't meant to be sequential. The user should be able to click on any `#img*` and get the corresponding video.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  `.live` was [removed](http://api.jquery.com/live/) a long time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class to the images and a data attribute.

```
<img id="img01" class="an_image" data-vid="1" />


$(".an_image").on('click', function() {
    $("#aaaLogo").fadeOut(100);

    var temp_var = $(this).data('vid');

    $("#frame").fadeIn(100, function() {
        vid01.show(setVideo(temp_var));
    });
});
```

You shouldn't use .live() anymore either (depending on the jQuery version you are using), they switched back to .on()

Comment: This is one way (+1).  You could also strip out the video number from the ID instead of adding the additional `data-` attributes.

Comment: I'm using `.live()` because the designer is using a jQuery carousel that uses `.clone()` and the click events don't pass through. With `.live()` the click events pass through to the clones.

Comment: I'll try it and let you know how it goes. Hopefully it won't break the carousel functionality.

Comment: I'm using jQ 1.7.11. I'd love to be able to update jQ but unfortunately this came to me this way; and they want it done yesterday so I don't have time to update and go through to replace them all with `.on()`.

However, I will update this on my own time and save it as a template moving forward.